# Connecting ruby application/script to a Ruby on Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, authentication

I am making an application where I want to have a sign-in within the ruby client app which is supposed to connects to a Ruby on Rails server. This is similar to what you do in applications such as Dropbox. The user somehow provides their username and password, and the ruby program should connect to the server establishing a session. After the initial sign-in I need to transfer data between the client and server (potentially a lot). I have looked at web-sockets for this, however I can't find a way to set this up properly.

The Rails server uses [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentification, and I would prefer to keep it that way if possible.

I have not been able to figure out how I can set up this connection. Any hints for where I should start looking?

Comment: Rails uses a simple cookie - called `_(app name)_session` by default - to track a client's session (same as practically any other web app with session support). That cookie is sent with the first response from the server (sign-in or otherwise), so provided you store it and send it back with all subsequent requests, you'd maintain the session.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a 'persisten' connection between your client and server, I suggest you use something like [0MQ](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall) socket which a kind of 'super-socket 'library with bindings for [ruby](http://zeromq.org/bindings%3aruby). On the server side, you would 'bind' to an IP/port, on the client side you would 'connect' and then you could use a connection type of REQ/REP (Request/Response). If, at any time the client disconnects, this doesn't 'blow' the binding on the server side. If the server side disconnects, this doesn't blow up the client side (it just block on waiting for the answer unless you define a timeout). 
There are other options also for non-blocking operation between the client and the server.